# Lost desktop in Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: unity, gnome, login-screen

I have Ubuntu 13.04 installed alongside Win 7 in a 10Gb recovery partition that has been fine.

I didn't like Unity, so was using Gnome desktop, no problems.

Today I noticed disc space on Ubuntu was low, so removed unwanted programs, including Cairo dock.

Now when I log in, I get a notice that Gnome desktop is not found (gulp)...Only option is <kbd>Log Out</kbd>

I can log in as guest and pull up a terminal, but not in sudo (I have a sudo user and password.

Any ideas out there please?

Answer (score 0):

try `su -` to change user as root

Comment: Logged in as guest (only option) and tried in a terminal but it returned 'Authentication error'

Comment: Solved by finally getting logged in as root and installing Gnome using the terminal.